# Passing a div tag from one.jsp into a function in another.jsp so it will display on one.jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

So I have a function in a jsp file that uses a dialog to prompt a confirm or cancel message. I then call this function in another jsp page. This would obviously keep displaying the dialog on the first jsp because of the div tag call. So I thought the best way to display this dialog in both jsp's would be to pass in the div tag from each page into the function.

**Question**

Is it possible to use a function in one jsp, pass in a div tag from another so that it display on the jsp that the function is called on? And how?

function executeConfirmDelete(nodeUniqueId, pageId) {

```
    $( pageId ).dialog({
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "Confirm",
                    "class" : "btn btn-primary button-width-medium",
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        deleteLANode(nodeUniqueId);
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "Cancel",
                    "class" : "btn btn-default",
                    click: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            ]
    });
    //basic css calls here and msgDialog string.

    $(pageId).dialog( "option", "title", "Confirm Delete Link" )
        .dialog("open")
        .html(msgDialog);

}
```

Comment: If you want information on one page to be sent to another page you'll have to store the information on your server. I recomment file_put_contents in php. The second page will call the contents.

Comment: "dialog to prompt a confirm or cancel message" - this sounds like javascript, not JSP. Perhaps you should show some code to make your question clearer?

Comment: So the pageId is the div from each jsp page